# PostgreSQL concatenation

Tags: postgresql, concatenation, plpgsql

I got this function to concat fields in my pgSQL-server:

```
BEGIN
    IF acc IS NULL OR acc = '' THEN
      RETURN instr;
    ELSE
      RETURN acc || ';' || instr;
    END IF;
  END;
```

It works great, but now I want this function to distinct equal entries. How can I do this?

Comment: Please supply more information. In particular, what is acc?  What is instr? Are these parameters? Are they the only fields/variables of interest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TYPE tp_concat AS (data TEXT[], delimiter TEXT);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION group_concat_iterate(_state tp_concat, _value TEXT, delimiter TEXT, is_distinct boolean)
  RETURNS tp_concat AS
$BODY$
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN $1 IS NULL THEN ARRAY[$2]
      WHEN $4 AND $1.data @> ARRAY[$2] THEN $1.data
      ELSE $1.data || $2
  END,
  $3
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION group_concat_finish(_state tp_concat)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
    SELECT array_to_string($1.data, $1.delimiter)
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'sql' VOLATILE;

CREATE AGGREGATE group_concat(text, text, boolean) (SFUNC = group_concat_iterate, STYPE = tp_concat, FINALFUNC = group_concat_finish);
```

Use it like this:

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(textfield, ';', TRUE)
FROM    mytable
```

if you don't want duplicates, and

```
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(textfield, ';', FALSE)
FROM    mytable
```

if you do.

Comment: See: [`aggregate_name (DISTINCT expression)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-expressions.html)

Comment: @Mike: also see the note about `DISTINCT` with multiple arguments.